# Passing partial active patterns as arguments?

Tags: f#, active-pattern

I'm learning F# by writing a recursive descent parser using active patterns.

Since all my rules or partial active patterns I need to combine them in different manners, but I'm getting really frustrated with the syntax of passing active patterns as parameters.

The following example shows the trouble I'm having:

```
// Combines two patterns by chaining them.
let (|Chain|_|) (|Pattern1|_|) (* Should I use pipes here? *) (|Pattern2|_|) data =
    match data with
    |Pattern1 result ->
        match result with
        |Pattern2 result2 -> Some result2
        |_ -> None
    |_ -> None 

// Stupid test patterns
let (|IfBiggerThan10ThenDouble|_|) value = if value > 10 then Some (value*2) else None
let (|IfLessThan100ThenDouble|_ |) value = if value < 100 then Some (value*2) else None

match 20 with
// Do I need pipes here?
|Chain (IfBiggerThan10ThenDouble IfLessThan100ThenDouble) value -> printfn "%A" value // Should print 80
| _ -> printfn "Did not match"
```

My main confusion seems to be about the '|' operator. Sometimes it seems to be a part of the type of the pattern and sometimes part of the name.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do not really need to implement your own chaining of patterns, because you can directly nest the patterns which gives you the required result:

```
match 20 with
| IfBiggerThan10ThenDouble(IfLessThan100ThenDouble value) -> printfn "%A" value
| _ -> printfn "Did not match"
```

This will first call the `IfBiggerThan10ThenDouble` pattern which calculates `20*2` and passes the value to the nested pattern `IfLessThan100ThenDouble`. This again doubles the value and binds it to the `value` symbol (when it succeeds).

That said, your implementation of the `Chain` pattern actually works and can be called like this:

```
match 20 with
| Chain (|IfBiggerThan10ThenDouble|_|) (|IfLessThan100ThenDouble|_|) value -> 
    printfn "%A" value // Should print 80
| _ -> printfn "Did not match"
```

In general, active pattern `(|P|_|)` is really just a function with a special name. You can treat it as an ordinary function and call it by writing `(|P|_|) argument` or you can treat it as a value and pass it as an argument to other functions or parameterized active patterns. Your code would work if you implemented `Chain` as a pattern taking ordinary functions:

```
let (|Chain|_|) f g data =
    f data |> Option.bind (fun r -> g data)
```

Then `Chain <arg1> <arg2> <pat>` is just calling the parameterized active pattern with two functions as an argument. When called, it binds the result to the pattern `<pat>`. In the above example, the two arguments are function values representing the patterns (these could be ordinary functions, but not lambda functions because of syntactic restrictions).

Comment: Great information! Is it possible to partially apply them as well?

Comment: @monoceres You can partially apply them when calling them as functions, e.g. `(|Chain|_|) f`. When using them as patterns, you can only partially apply exhaustive patterns (because partial patterns return option).

Comment: For example, given a pattern: `let (|Add|) a b = a + b`

Comment: You can actually write: `match 1 with Add f -> f 10`